# Can I make tagbar plugin highlighting the function my cursor is on?

Tags: highlight, plugin-tagbar

I want this highlight appear on the tagbar plugin window.

Can I?

Comment: What does the plugin's documentation say on the matter?

Comment: I found the tagbar documentaion from :help tagbar. I didn't use :help at all. I wish the help content be provided in a configured languages. Currently it maybe is only with english... But I understand I must read english though.

Comment: For better or for worse, English is the lingua franca of tech. Get used to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a standard functionality of the plugin:

[image]

The `highlighting` group used to highlight the tag is `TagbarHighlight`.

Comment: Hi! I found my vim also highlight the function my cursor is on. But I also found it takes time to highlight it. The time varies. Sometimes it is prompt. But the other times it is hugely long time. Maybe 3 to 5 seconds. Maybe this is why I thought my tagbar doesn't highlight. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-)